# Can I ask this on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I am new to web services in C# and I have no clue on how to start.

The web services I have to send requests to are implemented elsewhere (I have no idea how they are built or where). What I know is I have to send requests and catch the responses and show it to the user.

At this moment I send hard coded soap schemes requests and show dirty soap responses schemes.

I need to know how to let C# manage all the schemes etc. for me, so that I don't need to hard code everything. I need to know how to put requests and responses into objects.

Is it OK to put this on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Short answer: you need [Service References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx).

Comment: You won't be attacked and humiliated, but it sounds like you would be downvoted for not researching your own problem

Comment: Even so, its extremely rare that I ever see a user attacking someone - and their comments get flagged very quickly if this ever happens. You might get some probing questions asking you what you've actually done yourself but that isn't attacking anyone. Its trying to get you to describe your own problem as per the [ask] guidelines

Comment: If a comment is rude, flag it and it will be removed, otherwise I'm not sure what textually attacked means.

Comment: Is your comment really on topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question would likely be closed as too broad, or if worded slightly differently ("what tool do I need to implement this") as a recommendation request. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Only if you are running into concrete problems while *implementing* a solution, we are able to help you. Otherwise, the question isn't specific enough for the Stack Overflow Q&A format.

Comment: I was thinking maybe someone has read a good tutorial on this and can share it with me. But again I don't think SO will allow asking for a tutorial.

Comment: @ISeeSharp yes, because those kind of questions tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: ... and link rot.

Answer (score 6):

You'd be better off starting with reading a book about web services in c#. (No, we won't recommend one but the search engine of your choice should be able to find them and their reviews).

Once you've done that and have started coding you might have some concrete questions we could answer, prior to that that your questions will almost certainly be too broad for us.